# how to index np.nan in a DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, nan

I create a DataFrame `df` with some `nan` in the column `label`, how can i get the index of the `nan`??
I have try`df['label'] == np.nan`, but it seems doesn't work, While I　use `sum(df['Adj. Volume'] == 5090527.0)`, I can get the right answer, what happened? why `==np.nan` doesn't work?
The DataFrame is like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `isnull` to test for `NaN` values:

```
df[df['label'].isnull()]
```

This will return all rows in your df where the label is `NaN`

the equality operator doesn't work with `NaN` which is why `== np.NaN` doesn't work

`NaN` has the property that `np.NaN != np.NaN` which is counter-intuitive

Example:

```
In [5]:
s = pd.Series([0,np.NaN, 3])
s

Out[5]:
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
dtype: float64

In [6]:    
s == np.NaN

Out[6]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [7]:
s != s

Out[7]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

You can see in the last example if we test whether `s != s` it returns `True` for the `NaN` entry

Using `isnull` also gives the same result:

```
In [8]:
s.isnull()

Out[8]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

You can then access the `index` attribute of the above to get just the index values:

```
In [10]:
s[s.isnull()].index

Out[10]:
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I  got it, thinks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and then return `index` by `.index`:

```
print (df[df.label.isnull()].index)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'label':[4,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  C  label
0  1  7    4.0
1  2  8    NaN
2  3  9    NaN

print (df[df.label.isnull()].index)
Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
```